# Cron Job expression -for every hour from Friday 12AM ESt until Sunday 11:59 EST

Tags: cron, cron-task

How would I go about writing a Cron expression to trigger a cron job that runs every hour from Friday 12AM ESt until Sunday 11:59 EST.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
0   *   *   *   0,5,6
```

Breaking this down:

```
0: Run at minute 0 (modify to suit)
*: Run every hour
*: Run every day of the month
*: Run every month
0,5,6: Run on Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays (Sunday is 0)
```

Hope this helps! :)